# Hide tooltip in surveys on mouse hover

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, survey

I am using the surveys in SP 2010 to provide feedback on services. Rating level is made from 1-5 with radio checkbox and also I have framed two questions in the survey. Whenever mouse hover is made on the radio buttons the whole tag appears in the yellow standard tooltip.

I have added the questions by using two different tags in Additional Question Settings.

```
<br>How satisfied are you with the communications you received?<br/>
<br>How satisfied are you with the timeliness of how the incident was managed?<br/>
```

How could I possibly hide the tooltip?

Comment: <br> tag doesn't allow content within. Anyhow, I didn't get what you said about additional question settings. What is that you have done exactly?

Comment: In survey setting, under a single question I have differentiated these two. And now the yellow standard tooltip appears on mouse hover which needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://*yoursite*/Lists/*yoursurvey*/newform.aspx

Edit the page (site actions > edit page), then add a CEWP and link to a .js file you'll have put in eg. the SiteAssets library.

With this bit of jQuery you should be able to get rid of the tooltips:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("disableTooltips");

    function disableTooltips(){
        $('.ms-RadioText').removeAttr('title');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I uploaded this piece of code in StyleLibrary and referred this js in CEWP. and its still the same.<script type="text/javascript"> /* This bit of jQuery is used to get rid of yellow standard tooltip*/ $('.ms-RadioText').removeAttr('title'); </script>

Comment: make sure to fire it after the page has been fully loaded. Try using the _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myCustomFunctionName"); see http://www.stephanrocks.com/2011/10/05/_spbodyonloadfunctionnames-in-sharepoint-vs-jquerys-document-ready/

Comment: Is this formation correct?$('.ms-RadioText').removeAttr('title');
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myCustomFunctionName");

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: I used it and still I get to see the tooltips.

Comment: It works on my machine. dunno

Comment: Should I have to pass any values in ('title')

Comment: open up the developer toolbar and put a brakepoint on the line that reads $('.ms-RadioText').removeAttr('title'); This is to make sure the function is actually fired.

Comment: It ran successfully with no errors